# Recursion problem involving head, tail and xor

Tags: recursion, functional-programming

Consider a set of functions:

- `head(l)` returns first bit from list `l`, e.g.

  ```
  head([0,1,0]) = 0, 
  head([1]) = 1
  ```
- `tail(l)` returns a list by removing first element from `l`, e.g.

  ```
  tail([0,1,0]) = [1,0],
  tail([1]) = []
  ```
- `a:l` appends bit `a` to beginning of list `l`, e.g.

  ```
  1:[0,1,0] = [1,0,1,0].
  ```
- `xor` takes takes as input two bits and returns a bit.

  ```
  xor(a,b)
  if (a == b) 
    return(0)
  else 
    return(1)
  endif
  ```
- `f1` takes as input a list and returns another list.

  ```
  f1(s)
  if (s == []) then 
    return([1])
  else if (head(s) == 0) then  
    return(1:tail(s))
  else if (head(s) == 1) then 
    return(0:f1(tail(s)))
  endif
  ```

  - `f2` takes as input a bit and a list and returns a bit.

    f2(b,s)
    if (s == []) then 
      return(b)
    else if (head(s) == 0) then 
      return(f2(xor(b,1),tail(s)))
    else if (head(s) == 1) then 
      return(xor(b,1))
    endif
- `g1` takes as input a nonnegative number and returns a list.

  ```
  g1(n)
  if (n == 0) then 
    return([0])
  else 
    return f1(g1(n-1))
  endif
  ```
- `g2` takes as input a nonnegative number and returns a bit.

  ```
  g2(n)
  if (n == 0) then 
    return(0)
  else 
    return f2(g2(n-1),g1(n))
  endif
  ```

Can anyone explain what the function `g2()` returns?

I am able to find out g1() returns a list in binary
for example

```
g1(1) = [1]
g1(2) = [01]
g1(3) = [11]
g1(4) = [001]
```

Comment: Welcome! I am not sure this question suits this site; you are asking to figure out what a program computes without offering much of your own thought. What does `g1` compute *in general*.

Comment: btw, what programming language is this? At first it looked like Python, but the `endif` statements and missing colons after the `if` statements clearly indicate it's not.

Comment: You are wrong : g1(n) = [ n mod 2 ]

Comment: @DanielEberts this could be valid LUA code.

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

- g1(0) = [0] so you can see that f1 for [0] returns [1] and for [1] returns [0]. From here g1 must be clear.
- f2 takes a bit and a list of one element and returns a bit so it is one of the [boolean functions of 2 variables](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BooleanFunction.html) (they are only 16)
- after you know that g2(0) = 0 and the above hints it is easier to calculate g2

I can propose you to post your answer or I will update my answer after some time to be sure that it was not for homework.

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for your inputs. I am able to find what g2() returns.
g2(n)= 0 if n is even and 1 if n is odd.